# Есть ли в Java класс, реализующий метод с рассчетом RipeMd-128

Tags: java, хеширование

Нужно рассчитать для байтового массива сумму по алгоритму RipeMd-128. Никак не найду, как. Алгоритм очень сложный, чтобы писать самостоятельно. Тем болле, что должен работать очень быстро и с гарантией.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

стандартной реализации имхо нет (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest), но есть сторонние:

- бесплатная реализация: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-crypto/
- платная реализация: https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core_Crypto_Toolkits/JCA_JCE